# Python pubsub / message queue over HTTP?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, twisted, publish-subscribe, amqp

I have a python script that will run on a local machine that needs to access a message queue (RabbitMQ) or receive subscribed events over HTTP.  I've researched several solutions, but none seem natively designed to allow desktop clients to access them over HTTP.  I'm thinking that using Twisted as a proxy is an option as well.  Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use wamp http://wamp.ws/. Still experimenting with it, but it's working quite well at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Choice #1**
You may be interested in this [RabbitHub](https://github.com/brc859844/rabbithub)

**Choice #2**
If you want it to be on port#80, cant you do port forwarding using a proxy? It could be challenging, but

**Choice #3**
If your script is not tightly coupled with RMQ message format , you can try celery ( which uses RMQ underneath), then u can try [celery Http gateway](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway/) or [celery web hooks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html) if u want any other application to be triggered directly

It might be time consuming to get it up. However, Celery opens up loads of flexibility

**Choice #4**
For one of my projects, I developed an intermediate web service (Flask Service) to use RMQ
Not ideal, but it served the purpose at that time.